# How to get hash key from hash with nested arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

In my Ruby on Rails app I have this hash with nested arrays in it:

```
COLORS = {
  :red    => %w(draft open deactivated),
  :green  => %w(sent downloaded paid activated)
}
```

Is there a way to submit an array value like `draft` to get the corresponding hash key?

```
lookup_hash("draft") # => :red
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if the given element is present in more than one array? If that is not a problem

```
def lookup_hash(item)
  COLORS.find { |k, v| v.include?(item) }&.first
end
```

Comment: Thanks. No element will ever appear twice.

Comment: Perfect then! :)

Comment: Before Ruby 2.4 and safe navigation: `COLORS.find { |k, v| break k if v.include? "open" }`.

Comment: You changed name @AlekseiMatiushkin :O

Comment: Yeah, I had a challenge: gold badge in Elixir ⇒ name changed.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin safe navigation since Ruby 2.3 https://rubyinrails.com/2017/11/17/safe-navigation-operator-ampersand-dot-in-ruby/

Comment: If you are going to be doing this a lot you might want to invert the lookup table so that it is structured like `{ "draft" => :red, "open" => :red, "sent" => :green, ...}`.

Comment: @WizardofOgz: Would that be considerably faster?

Comment: @WizardofOgz: I don't like the repetition of `red` in there. But I am open for a better format.

Comment: Since a key (or `nil`) is desired, the following may read better (and avoids the need for the Safe Navation operator): `COLORS.each_key.find { |k| COLORS[k].include?(item) }`.

Comment: @Tintin81 It would be faster, but the operations are so small that it really only worth optimizing if this code will be called frequently. Since this is a look up table the repeated values aren't a problem, especially since they are symbols. In this case each usage of `:red` refers to the same global object.

Comment: Changing the Arrays to Sets will improve lookup speed. `%w(draft open deactivated).to_set`

Answer (score 3):

Another thought is to invert the hash for clearer code:

```
STATUS_COLORS = {
  draft: :red,
  open: :red,
  deactivated: :red,
  sent: :green,
  downloaded: :green,
  paid: :green,
  activated: :green,
}
```

Then you just do `STATUS_COLORS.fetch(status.to_sym)`. It's a little more verbose, but the code that accesses it is a little more readable.

Comment: We don't know, of course, whether the structure of `COLORS` is needed for purposes unrelated to this question. Also, why are the keys here symbols rather than strings? Aside from that, the concept would be useful if lookups must be made many times. Perhaps just use a variable (or instance variable): `hinvert = COLORS.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| v.each { |s| h[s] = k } }`. Then simply `hinvert[target]`.

Comment: We don't, I was just guessing from the context given in the question. It's symbols mostly by convention, but they're free to use strings if that fits their application better.